# How can I write a select query from a table which has columns like product,attribute,value?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, entity-attribute-value

I have tables like these

```
 - Products: PID,ProductName...
 - Attributes:AID,AttributeName...
 - ProductAttributes:PID,AID,Value
```

and the values are

```
***ProductAttributes***

 - P1,A1,V1
 - P1,A2,V2
 - P1,A3,V3
 - P2,A1,V4
 - P2,A2,V2
 - P2,A3,V3
 - P3,A1,V1
 - P3,A2,V2
 - P3,A3,V5
```

I need a procedure which has 2 array parameters and it filters products by these parameters. If `Parameter1:{A1,A2}` and `Parameter2:{V1,V2}` procedure should select

```
P1,P3
```

How can I write this? Thanks

Comment: Could you please describe the algorithm of the wanted procedure a little bit better, e.g. why should it return `P2` but not `P3`?

Comment: A "flexible" data model like that is highly inefficient. If you have any chance to change that, do it.

Comment: select * from ProductAttributes
where AID in ('A1','A2')
and Value in ('V1','V2')

Comment: @OcasoProtal For example: 
Monitor1,ScreenSize,21;
Monitor1,Type,LCD;
Montitor1,RefreshRate,2ms;
Monitor2,ScreenSize,24;
Monitor2,Type,LED;
Montitor2,RefreshRate,5ms;
Monitor3,ScreenSize,21;
Monitor3,Type,LED;
Montitor3,RefreshRate,2ms; 
and i want to list monitors which have 21" Screend and RefreshRate is 2ms.

Comment: @SamiBeyoglu So the result in your question (`P1,P2`) is wrong, you want `P1, P3`, because only P1 and P3 have the combination `A1,V1` and `A2,V2`?

Comment: @OcasoProtal Yes you're right. Sorry about that. I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming V1 must be a value for attribute A1, and V2 must be a value for attribute A2.  In other words, if you search for shoes with attributes ('canvascolor','solecolor') and values ('red','black'), then you don't want a shoe with black canvas and red soles.

Anytime you want to compare multiple attributes in a WHERE expression, they need to be on the same row.  This would be easy if you had a conventional relational table design, where each attribute is stored in a distinct column:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
WHERE p.canvascolor = 'red' AND p.solecolor = 'black';
```

You could also write this expression with tuple comparison:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
WHERE (p.canvascolor, p.solecolor) = ('red', 'black');
```

When you store attributes on multiple rows, as in this Entity-Attribute-Value table you are using, things get more complicated.  This is the tradeoff for having the flexibility EAV gives you to define attributes at will.  You need to use joins to get those onto the same row so you can compare:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
JOIN ProductAttributes pa1 ON pa1.PID = p.PID
JOIN Attributes a1 ON a1.AID = pa1.AID
JOIN ProductAttributes pa2 ON pa2.PID = p.PID
JOIN Attributes a2 ON a2.AID = pa2.AID
WHERE (a1.AttributeName, pa1.Value) = ('A1', 'V1')
 AND (a2.AttributeName, pa2.Value) = ('A2', 'V2');
```

Another way to do this is to match *either* attribute/value pair, and then group by the matching PID.  Groups where the count of matches is exactly two have the desired attributes & values.

```
SELECT p.PID, MAX(p.ProductName), ...
FROM Products p
JOIN ProductAttributes pa ON pa.PID = p.PID
JOIN Attributes a ON a.AID = pa.AID
WHERE (a.AttributeName, pa.Value) = ('A1', 'V1')
 OR (a.AttributeName, pa.Value) = ('A2', 'V2')
GROUP BY p.PID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```